Python package is not recognized even after installation
I installed Python
python -V
Python 3.12.2

I installed Python 3.12.2 and PIP and set PATH.

I uninstalled previous version
pip -V
pip 24.2

The package installs successfully. But does not run.

py -m pip install goslate

'goslate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Python packages are generally used inside Python code. Are you sure you're using the package correctly? EDIT: goslate.py instead of goslate - https://pypi.org/project/goslate/#command-line-interface

you seem to be calling goslate from the console instead of using it inside a python file

@Anonymous python goslate.py Test1.srt es did not work.

@toyotaSupra, this is not an installation issue, the package was installed fine.
As for the issue, "did not work" is meaningless. Read what the error says. The issue is probably that goslate.py is located inside your site-packages directory, not in your Digimon directory.

you need to post what is inside your goslate.py file that you are trying to execute

It seems like you are trying to run a Python script as a Python independent script. I don't know about the package, but I can say that Test1.srt es are the valid arguments, if your arguments are according to the package. Try running it with python module specification.
python -m goslate Test.srt es

Same like you did for package installation:
python -m pip install goslate

